# c/c++: How to find out the own library name

Tags: c++, c, linux, reflection

I would like to intercept a dynamically loaded shared library libA.so on a Linux system.
LD_PRELOAD does not work, because the libA.so is opened **explicitly**.
Can a function of a shared library determine its library name?
Then i could move some original libA.so to libA-org.so. And replace it with a new libA.so, that itself loads the libA-org.so and wraps it.
Or is there some simpler/better approach?

Well, i could use an active approach. There is a generic framework that loads the *.so files (common interface). I could extend that framework and let it check for wrapper images. But i am curious, if there is a non-intrusive way.

Comment: This is probably going to be OS specific, so what OS are you planning on running this on?

Comment: @MrEricSir .so implies Unix-like

Comment: @Code-Apprentice macOS, BSD, and Linux are just three flavours of what is *NIX that use `.so`, yet have wildly different internals and binary formats.

Comment: Neither C nor C++ directly addresses libraries *at all* except for a passing acknowledgment that the environment might provide such a facility.  Therefore, there absolutely is not any standard mechanism in either language by which you could obtain the information you want.

Comment: Since you tag [linux], I guess you're talking about ELF and about intercepting calls to `dlopen()`, `dlsym()`, etc..  These functions provide an interface to the dynamic linker, and ELF allows binaries to specify which dynamic linker to use.  In principle, therefore, if you are in control of the binary then you ought to be able to achieve what you're after by preparing and using your own variant dynamic linker.  That would be transparent at runtime, but it sure sounds like a tremendous hassle.

Comment: *`LD_PRELOAD` does not work, because the libA.so is opened explicitly.*  And just how is `libA.so` opened explicitly?  Via a call to `dlopen()`?  Well, then, interpose on `dlopen()`...

Answer (score 2):

> Can a function of a shared library determine its library name?

Yes, although solution you are looking for is OS specific. If you are interested in GNU libc-based approach, you should look at [`dladdr(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr).

The function can get a path to a hosting library by using its own address:

```
const char *location(void)
{
    Dl_info info;
    dladdr(&location, &info);
    return info->dli_fname;
}
```

According to Boost.Dll, this function should be available on QNX, Android, Solaris, MacOS and some BSDs too, but I haven't check this myself.

Or you can use Boost.Dll directly. It has everything required wrapped in a cross-platform way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This even works for c++ member functions. However, not for constructors? Do you know why?

Comment: @FrankBergemann You can try declaring static local variable `static const char location;` and use its address to pass it to `dladdr`.